# javac isn't working in Desktop and Documents Directory

Tags: java, javac

I installed jdk1.8.0_202 and set the path for jdk1.8.0_202/bin, jre1.8.0_202/bin and JAVA_HOME in both 'user variables' and 'system variables'.
I created a test java file on Desktop and opened cmd(non admin) and tried to compile which resulted in the following error.

> C:\Users\andey\Desktop>javac Main.java
>   Main.java:2: error: error while writing Main: Main.class (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   public class Main {
>          ^
>   1 error

Same happened with Documents folder and sub folders. I also tried using cmd(elevated) but I got same error.
I could compile successfully on any other folder except those 2 folders(Desktop and Documents) even using non-elevated cmd.
I want my programs to be either on desktop or in documents.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Main.java file is successfully being compiled and running when not in Desktop folder or documents folder. I got output 'Hello World' when the file is in Downloads folder.

Comment: Why is it so important to you that you *develop* the code in one of those two folders? Develop the elsewhere, create a runnable jar file with your code, the copy that to the folders and run it, if you really want to run the code from there. But again: Why?

Comment: I store all my programs in C, C++, python in documents folder. So I thought it'd be nicer to have all programs in one place. Also am just curious to know the reason for this error as it's not mentioned anywhere when I googled it.